# Can I used file patterns other than star with yum?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, glob, yum

I know for sure that yum does not support regular expression on its install commands but I wonder if there is a way to simulate it and have a single command that does:

- install python-foo or python2-foo packages (or both)
- does not install python3-foo packages

Usually the regex for this would be `python[2]?-foo`. How to do this with only yum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to obtain a similar kind of behaviour using

```
yum -y --exclude='python3*' install python*-foo
```

This method allows you to avoid installing other python versions than the desired ones. May not be perfect but it did the job in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no way other than using shell globbing patterns for searching among packages, you have to work around it by knowing a common part of package name like `python` that should be used in `yum` search then do a `grep` for narrowing down the results:

```
yum search python | grep -Po '(?i)^\S*?python2?-foo\S*' > packages
```

Then use `yum install $(cat packages)` to go through installation of all those.